# Quickly applying tweaks to data in XML file?

Tags: xml

I have a XML file with lots of lot of definitions that look like this:

```
<skill name="zeal" type="attack" posture="defense">
    <stats level="1" attack_mult="0.60" dmg_mult="0.20" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" /> 
    <stats level="2" attack_mult="0.70" dmg_mult="0.24" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
    <stats level="3" attack_mult="0.80" dmg_mult="0.28" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
    <stats level="4" attack_mult="0.90" dmg_mult="0.32" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
    <stats level="5" attack_mult="1.00" dmg_mult="0.36" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
</skill>
```

Now I want to tweak the data I have in that file, without editing each single value itself.
For example:

- Multiply all dmg_mult attributes by 2 (e.g. make dmg_mult="0.40" out of dmg_mult="0.20", etc.)
- Extrapolate a additional level from the existing ones. (E.g. see that attack_mult was increased by 0.10 and dmg_mult by 0.04, so insert a level 6 with attack_mult 1.10 and dmg_mult 0.40)

How can I apply such "tweaks" effectively to a XML file without wasting countless hours on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XSLT stylesheet to transform your XML to another XML with value multiplication and extrapolation (to a certain extent). [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) is a free XSLT processor to run the transformation.

The extrapolation is rather simple in my example, it takes the last two attribute values for `attack_mult` and `dmg_mult` and determines the difference, then adds it to the last attribute's value to extrapolate linearly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="skill">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:element name="stats">
        <xsl:attribute name="level">
          <xsl:value-of select="stats[last()]/@level+1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="attack_mult">
          <xsl:variable name="last_value" select="stats[last()]/@attack_mult"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number($last_value + ($last_value - stats[last()-1]/@attack_mult), '0.00')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="dmg_mult">
          <xsl:variable name="last_value" select="stats[last()]/@dmg_mult*2"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number($last_value + ($last_value - stats[last()-1]/@dmg_mult*2), '0.00')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="cooldown">
          <xsl:value-of select="stats[last()]/@cooldown"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="num_attacks">
          <xsl:value-of select="stats[last()]/@num_attacks"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="radius">
          <xsl:value-of select="stats[last()]/@radius"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="stats/@dmg_mult">
    <xsl:attribute name="dmg_mult">
      <xsl:value-of select=".*2"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<skill name="zeal" type="attack" posture="defense">
  <stats level="1" attack_mult="0.60" dmg_mult="0.4" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
  <stats level="2" attack_mult="0.70" dmg_mult="0.48" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
  <stats level="3" attack_mult="0.80" dmg_mult="0.56" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
  <stats level="4" attack_mult="0.90" dmg_mult="0.64" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
  <stats level="5" attack_mult="1.00" dmg_mult="0.72" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
  <stats level="6" attack_mult="1.10" dmg_mult="0.80" cooldown="65" num_attacks="1" radius="2.5" />
</skill>
```